# How to extract str() information in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
df<-data.frame(a=rnorm(20), 
               b=LETTERS[1:20], 
               c=rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each=10))
str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1.1525 0.0377 -0.2212 -2.6184 -0.3649 ...
 $ b: Factor w/ 20 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ c: logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
```

What I wanted is to extract the variable names and their class types from the `str()` output:

```
Names  Type
a      num
b      Factor
c      logi
```

How to realize this in R?

Comment: `lapply(df, class)`

Comment: `df2<-data.frame(Names=names(df), Type=sapply(df,class))`

Comment: Yes, I was just typing out the same line as @JohnPaul. `df2` does exactly as you ask.

Comment: Thanks all of you! It's very helpful!

Comment: I'd advise against `sapply` in favor of `lapply` for consistent output. If you have columns with more than one class (e.g., an ordered factor) `sapply` will return a list and break any code that was assuming it would return a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `str` only prints output and returns `NULL`. But, you can accomplish what you want with the `class` or `typeof` commands (depending on exactly the kind of information you want).

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20), 
                   b=LETTERS[1:20], 
                   c=rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), each=10))
sapply(df, class)
#         a         b         c 
# "numeric"  "factor" "logical" 
sapply(df, typeof)
#         a         b         c 
#  "double" "integer" "logical"
```

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentioned about extracting info from the `str`, we can use `capture.output` to get that as a string, then with `sub` remove the unwanted substring, and using `read.table` convert the `vector` to a two column `data.frame`

```
read.table(text=sub("\\$\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+).*", "\\1\\2",
  trimws(capture.output(str(df))[-1])), sep=":", 
  col.names = c("Names", "Type"), header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  Names   Type
#1     a    num
#2     b Factor
#3     c   logi
```